# Is it possible to execute Javascript code that was retrieved using pjax?

Tags: javascript, pjax

Let's say I have some simple Javascript like:

```
<script>
    var hello = function(){
        alert("Hello World!");
    }
</script>
```

.. on a page helloworld.html. If I loaded this script block into another page using Pjax. How do I execute the function hello()?

Comment: Well if you retrieved that over AJAX (which, essentially, is what PJAX is) and inserted it into your DOM, the script tag would execute on injection. Is that what you mean?

Comment: @Utkanos I have already tried inserting the script block into the DOM, but it does not appear to execute.

Comment: You're inserting the block as HTML, not as text, right? The former should definitely execute - does for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For security reasons, many browsers will not run Javascript injected by `innerHTML`, which I'm thinking Pjax likely uses. [(Here's a minimal example.)](http://jsfiddle.net/r4ZZG/)

Maybe the solution proposed in [Pjax's issue #48](https://github.com/defunkt/jquery-pjax/issues/48) will help

> What worked for me was to place my jQuery code in a function, call it
>   normally on document.ready (for non-pushState browsers), and then bind
>   the function to pjax:end, i.e.:
>
> ```
> $('body').bind 'pjax:end', mainFunction
> ```

Comment: That solution appears to be referring to the statement that "there's no way for the pjax success handler to be called on a 'back button' trigger".

Answer (score 1):

This is possible with PJAX. You just need to have the script tag with type `text/javascript`.

Code from PJAX library:

```
function executeScriptTags(scripts) {
  if (!scripts) return

  var existingScripts = $('script[src]')

  scripts.each(function() {
    var src = this.src
    var matchedScripts = existingScripts.filter(function() {
      return this.src === src
    })
    if (matchedScripts.length) {
      matchedScripts.remove();
    }
    console.error("FOUND SCRIPTS", scripts, matchedScripts.length);

    var script = document.createElement('script')
    script.type = $(this).attr('type')
    script.src = $(this).attr('src')
    document.head.appendChild(script)
  })
}
```